# Private Azure Functions with managed user-assigned identity? What roles to give AF, storage account?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-managed-identity, azure-storage-account

**tl;dr:** how do I create a private Azure Function, where the storage account created along with it is also private? Or I can set the storage account private later?

**I am new to Azure, and I'm using Azure portal. **

**I want** a private Azure Functions App that can be triggered by an external source (I either give the source an IP to whitelist or an Azure AD identity). The function handles private data, uses a secret from the Key Vault, does things to the data, and then stores the data in the same blob storage it got the data from. The original data is placed in the storage by the same external source triggering the function.

**I do not want** to create a private endpoint or a virtual network for this, as they are paid by the hour and do not suit my purpose.
I would like to be able to use Managed Identity or something else that only needs to be turned on if and when the external source decides the AF needs to be run.

When I create a public function app, and along with it a new public storage account, everything works. I create a function inside the AF called HttpTrigger1 without changing anything from the sample template. Everything is public, and I am able to run it just fine.

**The problem and previous attempts:**

- If I create a non-public function, I can't test HttpTrigger1 anymore
- All efforts to create the AF with an existing storage account with restricted access have failed (Your deployment failed), because it doesn't create those 3 automatic containers (azure-webjobs-hosts, azure-webjobs-secrets and scm-releases) in it if the storage account already exists. (Microsoft.Web/sites gives a Bad Request error for the app, because it can't be deployed without those containers)
- When I go and try to restrict the access to the newly created storage account and set it to allow only selected networks and IPs, without my IP address being whitelisted, leads me to be able to go to the function, but I can't see HttpTrigger1 sub function anymore. The function loses access to the storage account I guess?
- configuring the storage account to be enabled from selected virtual networks and IP addresses with my IP address being whitelisted, I can only see a host.json file where the HttpTrigger1 code should be in the code+test portion of HttpTrigger1 function

Current route: I am now trying to use managed identity to fix the problem. I created a new managed user assigned identity called testIdentity, and I assigned the testIdentity the Key Vault Secrets User role to my key vault.
I assume that similarly, I need to give that user assigned identity roles to my function and then the storage account. However, I don't know what roles they need to be given.
Can Azure Functions-created storage account even be restricted?
I reviewed the previously asked similar questions, and they seem to talk about external storage accounts they want to access, or maybe I'm confused.
Does anyone have a tutorial or guidance on how to make Azure Functions App, the storage account created with it, and the key vault all to see each other with managed identity or something else?

Answer (score 0):

It is now possible to secure almost all connections from Azure Functions with Managed Identity, including host connections to Azure Storage and Azure KeyVault. This official doc for [using identities with host connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-identity-based-connections-tutorial) covers the steps required to set this up.

As the doc mentions, you would need to give the function app's identity the `Storage Blob Data Owner` role to the Storage Account.

Comment: I tried following those instructions up to "Set up an identity and permissions for the app" and then changed the visibility of the container, resulting in the sample code in the code/test of httptrigger vanishing, but I guess I need to follow the instructions until the end of the document. Thank you